# Unity 5: Why Does my Scene Look Like This?

Tags: textures, shader, unity-game-engine, lighting, terrain

When I first load my game, my Main Menu scene looks perfectly fine. The mountains are the shade of white I like and everything is bright and just the way I made it in the scene view, like so:
[image: Everything is perfect!]

But when I go to a new scene (like About, or Options) and come back to my Main Menu scene, my mountains get darker and everything else in my scene gets darker and looks all weird, like this:
[image: Mountains are practically black and EVERYTHING in this scene is darker and looks weird.]

Does anyone know what is happening and how I can fix it? If you need more information or more pictures just let me know and I can provide that. Thank you! :)
EDIT: This occurs in both the "game view" and the "scene view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a problem with unity's lighting when you reload a scene at run-time the lights don't reload right. This problem doesn't occur when the game is built so no worries, just continue the development.

To fix this problem just go to Window -> Lighting -> Light-map Tab -> Disable Continuous Baking (Uncheck auto). Then click on bake to bake manually.

You'll have to rebake when you add a new light though.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I could not find the "Disable Continuous Baking" part and the "bake to bake manually" part... I am using Unity 5.2.3 if that makes any difference :) @primaël quemerais

Comment: Oh sorry, the option is now "auto" just uncheck the radio button to disable continuous bake ;)

Comment: Got it! I unchecked "auto", clicked on "Bake Reflection Probes", then clicked on "Build" and now it works perfectly! Thank you so much sir! :) @primaël quemerais

Comment: No problem ;) glad that helped you.